# Papaparse return value from csv file

Tags: javascript, csv, return-value, global, papaparse

I have made two functions to parse the CSV data with Papaparse, and one function to get the value from that data. The two functions use a return statement.

The problem I have is that the data I receive in Papaparse is always undefined. The value I would like to get is a mean value of the data in the CSV file. Here is a code snippet of where I would like the mean to be received:

```
function parseData() {

    var csvfile = "probeersel11.csv";

    $.get(csvfile, function (data) {
        var csvdata = Papa.parse(data, {
            header: true,
            skipEmptyLines: true,
            dynamicTyping: true
        });
        alert(doStuff(csvdata));

    });
}
```

The question is: how do I receive the right value here?

Comment: I tried your code and it works. Changed nothing, except for commenting the `doStuff()` call. `csvdata` is not empty despite Sugar's answer — I can see the parsed object. Using Papaparse v4.1.2.

Comment: @MatveyAndreyev not sure it is parsed object. I think it's parser instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[according to docs](http://papaparse.com/docs#local-files)

> ```
> Papa.parse(file, config)
> ```
>
> file is a File object obtained from the DOM.
>
> config is a config object which contains a callback.
>
> Doesn't return anything. Results are provided asynchronously to a callback function.

so `csvdata` will be empty. You should specify callback in your config and only then pass somewhere else